# Aligning WrapPanel with same Spacing Size

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

I'm trying to align my `WrapPanel` to have the same spacing size, although I can't figure out how. Here's an example of what I want,

[image]

**XAML Code:**

```
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding HolidayGenerator}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Any help is greatly apperciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't be sure that this will work, but I'm thinking that you may be able to coerce the vertical alignment of each column by setting the `ItemWidth` property on the `WrapPanel` (using a value that is appropriate based on the column width that you want it to render with):

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="25" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: Wow, I should of thought of that, I did that in HTML/CSS before. Thanks a lot chamila_c! It worked perfectly.